How to Implement a Garbage-Free Object Pool in Java?
My Java application has excessive garbage collection due to frequent object creation and disposal, so I want to implement an object pool to reuse objects and reduce GC overhead. How can I design a garbage-free object pool that dynamically adjusts its size (without creating garbage) based on application load? Can you provide an example implementation or guidance for pooling strategies, especially for handling pool growth?

Use a java.util.LinkedList?

@SpeedChaser I don't think java.util.LinkedList is garbage-free or high-performance

@SpeedChaser goal is to reduce load on GC, not increase it.

Manual memory management in java is tricky. It mostly depends on what life-cycle your objects have. Are you sure you want to go this way, maybe fine tuning GC will be enough. You may try to profile your app and optimize hot spots. Switching to zero memory footprint most likely will require to redesign your whole app.

Better to profile your app to determine which components are creating objects unnecessarily. eg objects allocated inside loops, and many adds to unsized collections such as HashMap / ArrayList.

Just to be a devil's advocate: "I'm considering implementing an object pool that can reuse objects." -> the Java heap and garbage collector is an object pool that can reuse objects. If you write your own, make sure it's not less performant than the GC.

Writing object pools was very popular in the early days of Java, when GC was very heavy; these days, it is much cheaper, and I would assume that the impact of GC is not an actual problem. Especially short-lived objects are very cheap in Java. Make sure that you actually have a problem before you write object pools, because they are likely worse for performance, and likely very prone to bugs.

@MarkRotteveel while what you say is true in general, every attempt is made to avoid garbage collection in high-frequency/algorithmic trading applications where 100% of all your transactions must have minimum latency: even a tenth of a millisecond of latency added to 0.1% of your transactions is too much.

@k314159 Sure, but writing a performant object pool is complex, and if not done correctly, probably worse than relying on GC. I'd say that in a lot of cases, like talex said, tuning GC is likely a better course of action before going down the route of writing an object pool.

I was about to answer it, but then it got closed. I have proposed some changes to the question.

Perhaps something like this will serve as a starting point for you.
List<D> objectsEmpty = new ArrayList<>();
List<D> objectslist = new ArrayList<>();
String dat = "1,Tom:2,Jack:3,Willy:4,Sam";

void init() {
   String data[] = dat.split( ":" );
   for( int i = 0; i < data.length; i ++ ) {
      objectslist.add( createObject( Integer.parseInt( 
              data[ i ].split( "," )[ 0 ] ),
              data[ i ].split( "," )[ 1 ] ) );
   }
   deleteObject( objectslist.remove( 2 ) );
   objectslist.add( createObject( 12, "Hardy" ) );
   for( int i = 0; i < objectslist.size(); i ++ ) {
      System.out.println( objectslist.get( i ).getName() );
   }
}

void deleteObject( D obj ) {
   obj.setName( "" );
   obj.setValue( 0 );
   objectsEmpty.add( obj ); 
}

D createObject( int value, String name ) {
   D newObject;
   if( objectsEmpty.isEmpty() ) {
      newObject = new D( value, name );
      objectslist.add( newObject );
      return newObject;
   }
     // modification suggested by k314159.
   newObject = objectsEmpty.remove( objectsEmpty.size() - 1 );
   newObject.setName( name );
   newObject.setValue( value );
   return newObject;
}

class D {

   int value = 0;
   String name = "";

   public D( int v, String n ) {
      value = v;
      name = n;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue( int value ) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName( String name ) {
      this.name = name;
   }

}


The whole point of avoiding GC is to improve performance (and especially latency), so it's important that a replacement be highly performant. objectsEmpty.remove( 0 ) will shift all elements of the list to the left. It's much faster to do objectsEmpty.remove(objectsEmpty.size() - 1).

Very good observation, if you don't mind, I put it in the answer.

I'll try something along these lines, thank you!

@TraderJenny, Glad to help you :).
